# Adding a Resource in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, kinect

So this is going to be extremely basic, but I'm not very familiar with Visual Studio. I'm working on programming the Kinect using KinectSDK and want to use the Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit. I've downloaded it and put

```
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf;
```

at the beginning of my program, but it doesn't recognize it. My question is, where should I place those files and how can I add this resource to my project? When I googled around, I get stuck at the "choose Global Resource File" because I don't see it anywhere. Could anybody provide a nice step by step instruction?

Comment: This may be of help to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That one is for Visual Studio 2008, I'm using 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console and enter:

```
Install-Package Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf
```

This should install all the necessary references.

Here's the link to [Nuget Documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/). It's the best way to manage external references in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to that DLL in your project.

[image]